# Create partner from code return empty list

Tags: odoo

I have a custom module and i want to create new partner from it

```
 class CustomerRegist(models.Model):
_name = "customer.regist"
_description = 'Customer Registration'
_inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
_rec_name='name'
_order='phone'

# def action_pass(self,vals_list):
#     return self.action_confirm(self,vals_list)
def action_done(self):

    if self.full_name:

        vals = {
        'name': self.full_name,
        'street': self.address_lineone,
        'street2': self.address_linetwo,
        'country_id': self.country_id.id,
        'city': self.city_id.id,
        'state_id': self.state_id.id,
        'zip': self.post_code,
        'phone': self.phone,
        'email': self.email,
        'customer_rank': 1,
        'supplier_rank': 0,
        'company_type': 'company',

    }

        self.state = 'active'
        self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)
        return True
    else:
     return False
full_name= fields.Char(string='full_name')
address_lineone = fields.Char(required=True,string='Address')
address_linetwo = fields.Char(string='Line 2')
city_id = fields.Many2one('country.city', required=True,string='City', help='Enter City')
post_code = fields.Char(required=True,string='Post Code')
state_id = fields.Many2one("res.country.state", string='State', help='Enter State', ondelete='restrict')
country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', string='Country', help='Select Country', ondelete='restrict')
phone_code = fields.Integer(string='Tel', related='country_id.phone_code', store=True)
phone = fields.Char(string='Phone')
email = fields.Char(required=True,string='Email')

class ConfirmWizard(models.TransientModel):
_name='confirm.wizard'
def action_confirm(self):
  return self.env['customer.regist'].action_done()
```

but the function return warning (Contacts require a name), or sometime created empty record in res.partner with False name

any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you functional workflow. But seems *self.full_name* may be empty. To avoid empty, we may try with email address or static word *Dummy* or any static word. For example,

```
def action_done(self):

    name=self.full_name or self.emaiil or "Dummy"

    vals={
            'name': name,
            'street': self.address_lineone,
            'street2': self.address_linetwo,
            'country_id': self.country_id.id,
            'city': self.city_id.id,
            'state_id': self.state_id.id,
            'zip': self.post_code,
            'phone': self.phone,
            'email': self.email,
            'customer_rank': 1,
            'supplier_rank': 0,
            'company_type': 'company',

    }

    self.state = 'active'
    self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)

    return True
```

Comment: your function create "Dummy" name only with empty records for another value

Comment: Yes. Because you don't have valid data first place. You can raise validationError if `self.full_name` is empty. Then we do not need to create with dummy.

Comment: this function called from another class, is that effect
  def action_confirm(self):
      return self.env['customer.regist'].action_done()

Comment: okay. what kind of value you expect in return?

Comment: I will edited the question to be more clear, I want to run the function from the wizard button

Comment: I edited my question to share more information, thanks for your help

Comment: This is wrong. You haven't passed any data/value from the 'confirm.wizard' method. Instead of call method of "customer.regist", why don't you develop a generic method in "confirm.wizard" object. `self` confirm.wizard object will store all values.

Comment: can you share your correct code, I am newly in odoo

Comment: That's your job buddy. I can help you or point out where is problem. Write entire logic in "action_confirm" method of 'confirm.wizard' object.

Answer (score 0):

resolved

```
  def action_confirm(self):

  partner = self.env['customer.regist'].browse(self.env.context.get('active_ids'))

  vals = {
      'name': partner.full_name,
      'street':partner.address_lineone,
      'street2': partner.address_linetwo,
      'country_id': partner.country_id.id,
      'city': partner.city_id.id,
      'state_id': partner.state_id.id,
      'zip': partner.post_code,
      'phone': partner.phone,
      'email': partner.email,
      'customer_rank': 1,
      'supplier_rank': 0,
      'company_type': 'company',

  }

  # self.state = 'active'
  self.env['res.partner'].create(vals)
  partner.state='active'
```